# PostgreSQL range-based join works too slow

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join

Supporse I have 2 tables with some Events and Callbacks with following structure:

```
Event:
id
timestamp (BIGINT, btree index)
type (VARCHAR, btree index)
(pair index (timestamp, type))

Callback:
id
timestamp (BIGINT, btree index)
event_type
```

Event table contains about (M=) 300000 rows, Callbacks is about (N=) 25000.
I try to do somethink like:

```
SELECT * FROM Callback
JOIN Event
ON ABS(Callback.timestamp - Event.Timestamp) < 300000 AND
    Callback.event_type = Event.type;
```

As it was planed, it should work for O(N log(M) + R) (where R - is result size. R is about 1000000 (AVG 50 events for each order)), but practicaly it works about 40 minutes on powerfull CPU.

**UPD:** Sorry, forget to say, I try:

```
SELECT * FROM Callback
JOIN Event
ON Event.Timestamp < Callback.timestamp + 300000 AND
   Event.Timestamp > Callback.timestamp - 300000 AND
   Callback.event_type = Event.type;
```

But nothing changes.

Can anyone tell, what I do wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? What is the execution plan for the query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work with an index on `event(type, timestamp)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Callback c JOIN
     Event e
     ON c.event_type = e.type AND e.Timestamp > c.timestamp - 300000;
```

The idea is to leave one of the timestamp columns with no modifications.  These can prevent the use of the index.

I do wonder if you also want a condition on `c.timestamp >= e.TimeStamp`.  Your performance problem might simply be the volume of data you are returning.

Answer (score 0):

Re-arrange your joins so that one column is expressed as a function of the other, so something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Callback
JOIN Event
ON (Event.Timestamp > (Callback.timestamp - 300000) AND
    Callback.event_type = Event.type);
```

... or ...

```
SELECT * FROM Callback
JOIN Event
ON (Callback.timestamp > (Event.Timestamp + 300000) AND
    Callback.event_type = Event.type);
```

(I think I got the >'s and <'s the right way round).

This allows indexes on the columns to be used, but I wouldn't rule out the possibility that full scans will be needed on both tables. It depends on the data distribution of the values.